# Unable to remove character inserted by Text Watcher in Android

Tags: android, textwatcher

I was using Text Watcher class to insert hyphen(-) after every four characters. I have also used OnKeyListener to check whether BackSpace or Delete key is pressed. But after pressing backspace, I am unable to delete hyphen. I searched a lot and found that this will not work for soft Keyboard. Am I right or is there any solution for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for masking input from EditText

I found code snippet here

http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-mask-with-edittext.html

hopes it helps you.

Comment: In the comments section of this page, you can see the bug (not able to delete blankspace). Same problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                            int start, int count, int after) {
                    }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                    }
```

Above methods return uneditable text. So use below method

```
@Ovverride
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
```

Be careful any change made to `Editable s` will call this method again. So prevent infinite looping